# Mindslaver and Conspiracy's vote cards

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Mindslaver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mindslaver) and my opponent has a [Coercive Portal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Coercive%20Portal) on the board. I use the Mindslaver's ability to take control of my opponent's next turn. Do I get to choose what his vote is for the Portal's ability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You make all decisions for that player, and what to vote for is a decision.

> 712.5. While controlling another player, a player makes all choices and decisions the controlled player is allowed to make or is told to make by the rules or by any objects. This includes choices and decisions about what to play, and choices and decisions called for by spells and abilities.